# Auto redirect to website version based on user country

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-redirect

I am trying to create auto redirect for my website based on a country of a
user. The website will be available only in 1 language but pricing will be
based on a country currency. It's a simple website with main page, terms and
conditions, privacy policy and that's all. My hosting provider is OVH and I
suppose they have Apache servers.

#### Here is what I am trying to do:

1. Main adress http://www.example.com
2. User in Poland with Polish language uses http://www.example.com . I also own a country domain http://www.example.pl
3. User in Canada with Polish language is auto redirected to http://www.example.com/ca
4. User in US with Polish language is auto redirected to http://www.example.com/us
5. All Polish users from countries other than Canada and US use http://www.example.com
6. OPTIONAL Users from Poland CAN'T acces version for canadian users, and vice versa
7. All users speaking English or any other language, in any country, access http://www.example.com. In the header I have links allowing to change language versions freely and go to http://www.someadress.com and vice versa.

#### EXAMPLE

- Go to [www.istockphoto.com](http://www.istockphoto.com)
- In my case I am redirected to http://www.istockphoto.com/ca
- In Poland I would be redirected to http://www.istockphoto.com/pl
- You will be auto redirected based on your country

#### SAMPLE CODE

I was trying to do it with php but it didn't work as intended. Servers are located in France and I was redirected to http://www.test.com

PHP:

```html
$country_code = $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY"];
if ($country_code=="PL") {$link = 'http://www.example.com';}
elseif ($country_code=="CA") {$link = 'http://www.example.com/ca';}
elseif ($country_code=="US") {$link = 'http://www.example.com/us';}
else {$link = 'http://www.test.com';}
header("location:$link");
exit;
```

I tried editing htaccess file but nothing happened:

```html
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{ENV:IP2LOCATION_COUNTRY_SHORT} ^PL$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com [L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:IP2LOCATION_COUNTRY_SHORT} ^CA$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/ca [L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:IP2LOCATION_COUNTRY_SHORT} ^US$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/us [L]
```

Any ideas how can I do it in the easiest possible way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you have the mod_geoip module (GeoIP Extension) installed on your server.

Then, tweak your .htaccess file accordingly :

```
GeoIPEnable On
GeoIPDBFile /path/to/GeoIP.dat

# Start Redirecting countries

# Canada
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^CA$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://ca.abcd.com$1 [L]

# India
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^IN$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://in.abcd.com$1 [L]

# etc etc etc...
```

Documentation: [URL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.geoip.php)